# Related record component - does not show action's default values

Tags: lightning-experience, quickaction, lightning-components, lightning-record-page

I am using Lightning in my org

I have a requirement to have a tab for resolving a case

For this I have created a new case quick action - I called it `Resolve Case`.

Also I have set the `Status` field default value to 'Resolved` because I want that this field would be set to 'Resolved' automatically.

When I use this quick action as a button - the popup is loaded with the default value as expected:

[image]

**PROBLEM**

When I use this quick action as a `Related Record` component in the Lightning App Builder - the default value does not load when The component loads:

[image]

**QUESTION**

Can default action values be used in a `Related Record` component?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of inconsistencies is a known issue (under review): https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001Yn5PQAS.

Mind that there are other inconsistencies under reviews as well in the current release (Spring '20). E.g. when fields used in Related Record components are updated multiple times, the RR component in some cases does not reflect the correct value, not until a couple of minutes have passed, or after user logout/login (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001HlUDQA0).

Safest use case is to use the action button to change objects, not inline editing at the moment.